# How to test Context key value set from Server Interceptor

Tags: java, grpc

I'm trying to write a unit test for my authentication server interceptor. Interceptor extracts User ID information from the attached metadata header and stores it as ContextKey, which is later used in service calls. I've done this based on the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929156/how-to-pass-data-from-grpc-interceptor-to-service-method-call) thread.

Based on [HeaderServerInterceptorTest](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/header/HeaderServerInterceptorTest.java) example, I've set up my own test which indeed invokes the interceptor. However, when trying to assert the User ID value, it is always null.

My interceptor class is:

```java
@Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers,
            ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

// authentication and extracting user ID info

        Context context = Context.current();
        return Contexts.interceptCall(context.withValue(USER_ID, id), call, headers, next);
    }
```

Assert always fails since USER_ID value is null.

```java
assertEquals("john_doe_ID", MyServerInterceptor.getUserID());
```

I'm guessing I'm missing some additional configuration for Context in my test, but I couldn't find anything similar...

Comment: You must retrieve the User ID value in the call listener thread (requestStreamObserver thread), which is under the context, otherwise different thread is under different context, and the User ID value is null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user675693 . It worked from call listener thread...